# Worklight 6.1 submitLoginForm timeout seems not to work

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

I have build the WL app using form based authenticator. However I have expected timeout option will work when the app can't reach WL server, it seems not to work.
What is wrong with my code below?

```
$('#login-button').on('click', function () {
var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
var options = {};
options.parameters = {
      j_username : $('#login-name').val(),
      j_password : $('#login-pass').val(),
};
options.headers = {};
options.timeout = 3000 ;
challengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, challengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);});
```

Comment: Hi; if your application cannot reach the Worklight server, why would it get challenged in the first place?

Comment: There is always a window where connection can be lost between challenge and submission. So timeout should be dealt with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @djna said, connection can be lost at any point of time.

If you would like to test Worklight server connectivity then you can try this option.

It is a suggestion, lets see whether this solve your problem

```
 $('#login-button').on('click', function () {
   WL.Client.connect({ 
     onSuccess: connected, 
     onFailure: notconnected,
     timeout: 3000
    });
});

function connected(response){
    var reqURL = '/j_security_check';
    var options = {};
    options.parameters = {
        j_username : $('#login-name').val(),
        j_password : $('#login-pass').val(),
    };
    options.headers = {};
    challengeHandler.submitLoginForm(reqURL, options, challengeHandler.submitLoginFormCallback);});
}

function notconnected(response){
    alert("not connected");
}
```